# Каково происхождение глагола "примоститься"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

На заднем сиденье между двух мальчишек **примостился** лохматый пес. [Евгений Велтистов.  (1971)]

ПРИМОСТИТЬСЯ,  св. Разг. Поместиться, пристроиться в неудобном месте, положении (сбоку, с краю и т.п.). П. у окна. П. на раскладушке у двери.

**Примоститься** ― это пристроиться, но при чем тут **мост**? И как давно это слово появилось в русском языке?

Comment: Начать надо, наверно, со связки "мост" — "мостить(ся)"

Comment: Это да, слова явно однокоренные. Но почему вместо "пристроиться" говорят "примоститься". Это какая-то метафора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мостовая,  помост, мостить - родственны слову примоститься.  Что же по сути представляет собой мостовая ранее? - Это набор досок, плотно прижатых друг к другу.  Следовательно, их кто-то примостил, приладил.  Так же создавались и мостки(переходы через болота, ручьи, канавы, весенние распутицы и т. д),  и деревянные мосты.  В  древности русичи говорили так: помыть ся, остановить ся, успокоить ся...
Что значило: помыть себя, остановить себя, успокоить себя. Отсюда и примостить ся - примостить себя, то есть, к чему либо себя пристроить.

Comment: Глаголы пристроить (ся) и примостить (ся) близки по значению и стилю ПРИСТРОИТЬ 1. что. Построить в дополнение к чему-л. П. веранду.  3. кого-что. Разг. Поместить,  устроить кого-, что-л. П. ребёнка на коленях. П. чемодан на полку.ПРИМОСТИТЬ,  Разг. Поместить в неудобном месте (сбоку, с краю и т.п.). П. чемодан в проходе вагона. П. в углу тумбочку. Но нейтральный смысл глагола "пристроить" ясен, так зачем заменять его  глаголом "примостить", у которого нейтральный смысл узко конкретный и связан с постройкой дороги МОСТИТЬ,  Покрывать камнем, брусчаткой.  Делать настил из досок, брёвен.

Comment: Мосты строят, сооружают,  а вот мостки - мостят. На болотах, к примеру, либо над грязью. Делать это не удобно.  Подобные соружения  не долговечны, следовательно, - временны. Вот вам и схожесть семантики со словом "примостится".  А ребёнка пристроить можно не только на колени, но и в школу, в детский сад, в бассейн.

Comment: Понять метафорический смысл глагола мне помог этимологический словарь, где было сказано, что мост - это брусок, рейка, перекладина (мачта - ближайшее родственное слово) или настил из них. Бросил несколько перекладин и примостился (устроился). А потом (развитие значение слова) просто нашел подходящее  временное местечко.

Answer (score 2):

В.Даль утверждает, что  ПРИМАЩИВАТЬ, примостить - это  прибавить к мощеному, вымостить далее, более.

Примостить что к чему - пригородить, пристроить легкую, деревянную постройку, или мостки, леса.

Примащиваться, примоститься, страдат. и возвр. по смыслу. Каменщик примостился на лесах для работы, подмостился. Примащиванье - длит., примощенье - окончат. ;   примост м. примостка ж. об. действ. по глаг.

Примост и примосток, подмост, помост, леса при стройке, или иная возвышенная настилка при чем-либо, сбоку.

Род нар или кутника в избе. Где сени зовут мостом, там крытая лестница к ним - примост.

Примостки, леса для стройки здания. Примостовник, примостовница, пск. твер. попрошайка, нищий, нередко сидящий у моста.
https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

То есть примоститься - пристроиться = пристроить себя где-нибудь на мостках, на лесах, в пристройке,  т.е. в неудобном месте.

Answer (score 2):

**Всё сказано верно в ответах,** то есть примоститься – это пристроиться, да еще в неудобном месте. Но и в словарях то же самое написано.

Мне же хотелось, чтобы кто-нибудь раскрыл **смысл метафоры**.
Ведь когда-то это выражение прозвучало впервые, и  в нем чувствовалось свежее сравнение, наблюдение человека с хорошим чувством языка.

**В словаре у Черных** указано, что этимология слова ***мост*** тесно связано с такими понятиями, как столб, мачта, брус, жердь, шест. **Мост – это сооружение из перекладин или постройка на сваях, на столбах.** Уже позже (в 15 веке) появились слова ***мостовой, мостить***.

Настил из перекладин – это более простая конструкция, чем пристройка, то есть примостить – это  пристроить что-то **на скорую руку**. Образно говоря, **всего-то добавить несколько перекладин.**

Именно поэтому ***примоститься*** – это  пристроиться временно и не очень удобно.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить к Вашему ответу ссылку на словарь Трубачёва. "Эволюция семантики слова *mostъ была связана с развитием техники строительства. Первоначально это 'то, что брошено (в болото, в грязь)' и 'то, что переброшено (через ручей, овраг)'. ... В дальнейшем слово *mostъ и производные отражают семантику '**укладывать, стелить, настилать, устраивать**' и т.д." (в том числе там речь идёт о том, чтобы стелить постель, стелиться спать и т.п.). При этом никакой связи со словом место мне найти не удалось.

Comment: Черных рассматривает две версии происхождения слова: а) от глагола метать (и.-е. корень met): б) от и.-е. корня mazd (брусок, бревно, мачта и др), но второй вариант считает более предпочтительным.